# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {COUNT(SSN)}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I use ReactJS with MySQL and NodeJS, i connet it with the data base and success, but here i want to find the count of users and display, the mysql is right but it can't display the count and there are this error:

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {COUNT(SSN)}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect  } from 'react';
    import Axios from 'axios';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    
    
    export const ReportsTable = () => {
    
      const [data1, setData1] = useState(0);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        debugger;
        Axios
          .get("http://localhost:3003/reports1")
          .then(result => setData1(result.data));
        console.log(data1);
        debugger;
      }, );   

 return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data1}</h1>
    </div>
 ) }

 export default ReportsTable;
```

And this is the index.js file in the server folder

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql')
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "finaldatabase"
});

app.get("/reports1", (req, res) => {
   db.query("SELECT COUNT(SSN) FROM usertype WHERE TypeID = 1 ", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log(result)
      res.send(result)
    }
  })
});

app.listen(3003, () => {
  console.log("running on port 3003");
})
```

In the console, it is print the result = 0

Comment: Once fetched, `data1` is an object and cannot be rendered. Use  `<h1>{JSON.stringify(data1)}</h1>` instead

Comment: Thank you, it is successful. But it display as this: [{"COUNT(SSN)":2}]
 How can i view the number only?

Comment: Since `data1` is an array with a single object, you can get the number as `data1[0]["COUNT(SSN)"]` and that should give you the number. Also, to make the field name easy-to-use, you can alias the count in backend as `SELECT COUNT(SSN) as count FROM usertype WHERE TypeID = 1`